# OnClick in Fragment not responding

Tags: android, android-fragments, uiimageview, onclick

I'm having an issue with setting up a OnClick within a fragment to my ImageView XML.

I have a ViewPager that displays a ImageView and a Progress bar inside when the app is running to display images that you can swipe through.

I am aiming to make it so when the user clicks on the image that is currently being displayed,
it comes up with a toast message.

The problem I am having is that nothing happens once I click on the image that is currently in view.

Any help would be great, thanks.

XML to fragment that controls ImageView and Progress bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

RecyclingImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment that controls ImageView:

```
public class ImageDetailFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA = "extra_image_data";
private String mImageUrl;
private RecyclingImageView mImageView;
private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;

public static ImageDetailFragment newInstance(String imageUrl) {
    final ImageDetailFragment f = new ImageDetailFragment();

    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA, imageUrl);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

public ImageDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mImageUrl = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(
            IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA) : null;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment,
        container, false);

     mImageView = (RecyclingImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cilcked..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  });

return v;
 }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (Batmanark.class.isInstance(getActivity())) {
        mImageFetcher = ((Batmanark) getActivity()).getImageFetcher();
        mImageFetcher.loadImage(mImageUrl, mImageView);
    }

    // Pass clicks on the ImageView to the parent activity to handle
    if (OnClickListener.class.isInstance(getActivity())
            && Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
        mImageView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) getActivity());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mImageView != null) {
        // Cancel any pending image work
        ImageWorker.cancelWork(mImageView);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
}
}
```

ViewPager XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/rellayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="AdIdHere"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPager Class:

```
public class Batmanark extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String IMAGE_CACHE_DIR = "images";
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "extra_image";

private ImagePagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;
private ViewPager mPager;

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Utils.enableStrictMode();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_detail_pager);

    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    final int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    final int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;


    final int longest = (height > width ? height : width) / 2;

    ImageCache.ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCache.ImageCacheParams(
            this, IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);
    cacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(0.25f); 


    mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher(this, longest);
    mImageFetcher.addImageCache(getSupportFragmentManager(), cacheParams);
    mImageFetcher.setImageFadeIn(false);


    mAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            Images.imageUrlsBatmanark.length);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setPageMargin((int) getResources().getDimension(
            R.dimen.image_detail_pager_margin));
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);


    getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        mPager.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int vis) {
                if ((vis & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) != 0) {
                    actionBar.hide();
                } else {
                    actionBar.show();
                }
            }
        });


        mPager.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
        actionBar.hide();
    }


    final int extraCurrentItem = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, -1);
    if (extraCurrentItem != -1) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(extraCurrentItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(false);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(true);
    mImageFetcher.flushCache();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mImageFetcher.closeCache();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.clear_cache:
        mImageFetcher.clearCache();
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.clear_cache_complete_toast,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public ImageFetcher getImageFetcher() {
    return mImageFetcher;
}


private class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final int mSize;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        mSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ImageDetailFragment
                .newInstance(Images.imageUrlsBatmanark[position]);
    }
}


@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final int vis = mPager.getSystemUiVisibility();
    if ((vis & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) != 0) {
        mPager.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mPager.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to set the onClickListener to the ImageView, not the whole View!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you have wrongly set the click listener on the besides setting it for the `ImageView`. Try as below besides `v.setOnclick...` set `mImageView.setOnClic...` as below:

> ```
>     mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
>       mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>        @Override
>        public void onClick(View arg0) {
>              Toast.makeText(context, "Cilcked..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>      }
>   });
> ```

**EDITED:**

Try to set the context in your `Toast` as `getActivity()` besides `context`

Initialize your `Imageview` as below:

> ```
>   private RecyclingImageView mImageView; 
>       mImageView = (RecyclingImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
> ```

Comment: I have updated my class using this code so you can see what it looks like. For some reason, this isn't working either?

Comment: In your onActivityCreated you don't have to call the click listener explicitly Just remove that click listener. And also in your `onCreateView()` method just create single instance of `ImageView` remove second `ImageView` below click listener.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the fixes, and it is still not working, hmm?

Comment: You have used the `RecycledImageView` in your layout so you must have to cast it using the same check my updated answer.

Comment: I have made the edits, is that you meant? It's still not functioning.

Comment: Remove this line `mImageView = (RecyclingImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);` which is above `return v;`

Comment: I've just removed it, and it still isn't working. See my updated code, no idea why this isn't working. Would it be something to do with the Viewpager class?

Comment: I have tried tagging the onClick and nothing seems to be showing up. What do you mean by "check the code now"?

Comment: I mean try to set the debug point on onClick and check whether it goes inside it or not ?

Comment: No it does not go inside the onClick

Comment: That means your `onClick` method is not getting called and not executing even.

Comment: As you have added the ProgressBar in your layout it might happening because of that. try to comment the ProgressBar in your layout and check for the event on ImageView. If you do not have any use of ProgressBar please remove it from layout.

Comment: I have use for the progress bar. This is really strange why the code isn't going inside the onClick method.

Comment: @Jack Hey try to comment on this code `// Pass clicks on the ImageView to the parent activity to handle
    if (OnClickListener.class.isInstance(getActivity())
            && Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
        mImageView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) getActivity());
    }` in your `onActivityCreate()` and then check.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been up all night trying to figure this out, much appreciated, have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Cilcked..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: I have updated my class using this code so you can see what it looks like. For some reason, this isn't working either?

Comment: Just create the mImageView and set the onClickListener once. Do it inside onCreateView.